# Swift do catch inside function doesn't work

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I have a function which parses JSON, but I get a nil error dealing with the URL strings:

```
var jsonResponse: NSMutableDictionary?
do{
    jsonResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
        options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSMutableDictionary;

    let info : NSArray =  jsonResponse!.valueForKey("latest_receipt_info") as! NSArray
    let transaction_id: String? = info[0].valueForKey("transaction_id") as? String
    let purchase_date: String? = info[0].valueForKey("purchase_date") as? String
    let product_id: String? = info[0].valueForKey("product_id") as? String
    let web_order_line_item_id: String? = info[0].valueForKey("web_order_line_item_id") as? String

    print("test")

    // Send Values  

    let addIAPUrl:NSString = "http://bla.com/application/addIAP.php?transaction_id=\(transaction_id!)&purchase_date=\(purchase_date)&product_id=\(product_id)&web_order_line_item_id=\(web_order_line_item_id)&userID=\(prefs.valueForKey("userID") as! String!)"
   self.apiRequests(addIAPUrl as String, completionHandler: { (success, message) -> Void in

             print("success \(addIAPUrl)")

        if(success == 1){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                // ADDED
                print("success \(addIAPUrl)")

            }

        }else{

           // DONT ADDED
        }



    })
```

The output doesn't return any error but the function fails after **print("test")**. The apiRequests function works in other cases, but doesn't seem to work in this context.

I would appreciate any help finding the problem.

Here is the code for the `apiRequest` function:

```
func apiRequests(url : String, completionHandler : ((success : Int, message : String) -> Void)) {

      guard let url = NSURL(string: url as String) else {

          return
      }

      let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
      let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
      let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

      let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data,  response, error) in
          guard let responseData = data else {

              return
          }
          guard error == nil else {

              print(error)
              return
          }

          let post: NSDictionary
          do {
              post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                  options: []) as! NSDictionary
          } catch  {

              return
          }

          let numberFromString = Int((post["success"] as? String)!)


          completionHandler(success: (numberFromString)!, message: (post["message"] as? String)!)



      })
      task.resume()

  }
```

Comment: What and where exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: @thislooksfun i didnt got any error dont run self.apiRequests function

Comment: Do you `catch` anything in the first snippet?

Comment: @vadian no looking everything good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is most likely that your `apiRequests:` function is erroring at one of many places, and is returning instead of calling your callback with an error state.

```
func apiRequests(url : String, completionHandler : ((success : Int, message : String) -> Void)) {

    guard let url = NSURL(string: url as String) else {
        completionHandler(0, "Couldn't get URL")
        return
    }

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data,  response, error) in
        guard let responseData = data else {
            completionHandler(0, "Data was nil")
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error)
            completionHandler(0, "Error wasn't nil")
            return
        }

        let post: NSDictionary
        do {
            post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                options: []) as! NSDictionary
        } catch  {
            completionHandler(0, "Error with NSJSONSerialization")
            return
        }

        let numberFromString = Int((post["success"] as? String)!)


        completionHandler(success: (numberFromString)!, message: (post["message"] as? String)!)



    })
    task.resume()

}
```

Side note, but not related to the fix,

```
 let addIAPUrl:NSString = "http://bla.com/application/addIAP.php?transaction_id=\(transaction_id!)&purchase_date=\(purchase_date)&product_id=\(product_id)&web_order_line_item_id=\(web_order_line_item_id)&userID=\(prefs.valueForKey("userID") as! String!)"
 self.apiRequests(addIAPUrl as String, completionHandler: { (success, message) -> Void in
```

Can easily be replaced with

```
let addIAPUrl = "http://bla.com/application/addIAP.php?transaction_id=\(transaction_id!)&purchase_date=\(purchase_date)&product_id=\(product_id)&web_order_line_item_id=\(web_order_line_item_id)&userID=\(prefs.valueForKey("userID") as! String!)"
self.apiRequests(addIAPUrl, completionHandler: { (success, message) -> Void in
```

Because you are converting a `String` to an `NSString` then *back* to a `String`

Comment: This is why I gave up writing my own api and just use [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: @thislooksfun great dude ty